# How to to find smallest (optimized) distance between two vectors in C++

Tags: c++, dlib, least-squares

I'm translating Python's version of 'page_dewarper' (https://mzucker.github.io/2016/08/15/page-dewarping.html) into C++. I'm going to use dlib, which is a fantastic tool, that helped me in a few optimization problems before. In line 748 of Github repo (https://github.com/mzucker/page_dewarp/blob/master/page_dewarp.py) Matt uses optimize function from Scipy, to find the minimal distance between two vectors. I think, my C++ equivalent should be solve_least_squares_lm() or solve_least_squares(). I'll give a concrete example to analyze.

My data:
a) dstpoints is a vector with OpenCV points - `std::vector<cv::Point2f>` (I have 162 points in this example, they are not changing),
b) ppts is also `std::vector<cv::Point2f>` and the same size as dstpoints.

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> ppts = project_keypoints(params, input);
```

It is dependent on:
- `dlib::column_vector` 'input' is 2*162=324 long and is not changing,
- `dlib::column_vector` 'params' is 189 long and its values should be changed to get the minimal value of variable 'suma', something like this:

```
    double suma = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<dstpoints_size; i++)
    {
        suma += pow(dstpoints[i].x - ppts[i].x, 2);
        suma += pow(dstpoints[i].y - ppts[i].y, 2);
    }
```

I'm looking for 'params' vector that will give me the smallest value of 'suma' variable. Least squares algorithm seems to be a good option to solve it: http://dlib.net/dlib/optimization/optimization_least_squares_abstract.h.html#solve_least_squares, but I don't know if it is good for my case.
I think, my problem is that for every different 'params' vector I get different 'ppts' vector, not only single value, and I don't know if `solve_least_squares` function can match my example.
I must calculate residual for every point. I think, my 'list' from aforementioned link should be something like this:

```
(ppts[i].x - dstpoints[i].x, ppts[i].y - dstpoints[i].y, ppts[i+1].x - dstpoints[i+1].x, ppts[i+1].y - dstpoints[i+1].y, etc.)
```

, where 'ppts' vector depends on 'params' vector and then this problem can be solved with least squares algorithm. I don't know how to create data_samples with these assumptions, because it requires `dlib::input_vector` for every sample, as it is shown in example: http://dlib.net/least_squares_ex.cpp.html.
Am I thinking right?

Comment: I don't understand what the vector `params` does. Is it necessary for solving your problem?

Comment: 'params' vector contains information like: output rotation vector, output translation vector, coordinates of image keypoints. They are stored as normalized values (between -1 and +1). I can calculate 'params' vector for original image and my problem is how to change elements of 'params' vector to get vector 'ppts' that is as close as possible to vector 'dstpoints'. I'm looking for method to optimize distance between vectors 'dstpoints' and 'ppts', and I think least_squares algorithm could be good to do it. Let me know if I explained it sufficiently.

Comment: Yes - now I understand. As far as I know you clearly need data samples for solving the least-squares problem. Wikipedia also says: "Most algorithms involve choosing initial values for the parameters."

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing this days. My solution is writing a Powell Class by myself. It works, but really slowly. The program takes 2 minutes in dewarping linguistics_thesis.jpg.
I don't know what cause the program running so slowly. Maybe because of the algorithm or the code has some extra loop.  I'm a Chinese student and my school only have java lessons. So it is normal if you find some extra codes in my codes. 
Here is my Powell class.

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
class MyPowell
{
public:
    vector<vector<double>> xi;
    vector<double> pcom;
    vector<double> xicom;

    vector<Point2d> dstpoints;
    vector<double> myparams;
    vector<double> params;
    vector<Point> keypoint_index;

    Point2d dst_br;
    Point2d dims;
    int N;
    int itmax;
    int ncom;
    int iter;
    double fret, ftol;

    int usingAorB;

    MyPowell(vector<Point2d> &dstpoints, vector<double> &params, vector<Point> &keypoint_index);
    MyPowell(Point2d &dst_br, vector<double> &params, Point2d & dims);
    MyPowell();
    double obj(vector<double> &params);

    void powell(vector<double> &p, vector<vector<double>> &xi, double ftol, double &fret);

    double sign(double a);// , double b);
    double sqr(double a);

    void linmin(vector<double> &p, vector<double> &xit, int n, double &fret);
    void mnbrak(double & ax, double & bx, double & cx,
        double & fa, double & fb, double & fc);
    double f1dim(double x);
    double brent(double ax, double bx, double cx, double & xmin, double tol);

    vector<double> usePowell();

    void erase(vector<double>& pbar, vector<double> &prr, vector<double> &pr);
};


#include"Powell.h"

MyPowell::MyPowell(vector<Point2d> &dstpoints, vector<double>& params, vector<Point> &keypoint_index)
{
    this->dstpoints = dstpoints;
    this->myparams = params;
    this->keypoint_index = keypoint_index;

    N = params.size();
    itmax = N * N;
    usingAorB = 1;
}

MyPowell::MyPowell(Point2d & dst_br, vector<double>& params, Point2d & dims)
{
    this->dst_br = dst_br;
    this->myparams.push_back(dims.x);
    this->myparams.push_back(dims.y);
    this->params = params;
    this->dims = dims;

    N = 2;
    itmax = N * 1000;
    usingAorB = 2;
}

MyPowell::MyPowell()
{
    usingAorB = 3;

}

double MyPowell::obj(vector<double> &myparams)
{
    if (1 == usingAorB)
    {
        vector<Point2d> ppts = Dewarp::projectKeypoints(keypoint_index, myparams);

        double total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ppts.size(); i++)
        {
            double x = dstpoints[i].x - ppts[i].x;
            double y = dstpoints[i].y - ppts[i].y;
            total += (x * x + y * y);
        }
        return total;
    }
    else if(2 == usingAorB)
    {
        dims.x = myparams[0];
        dims.y = myparams[1];
        //cout << "dims.x " << dims.x << "  dims.y " << dims.y << endl;
        vector<Point2d> vdims = { dims };
        vector<Point2d> proj_br = Dewarp::projectXY(vdims, params);

        double total = 0;

        double x = dst_br.x - proj_br[0].x;
        double y = dst_br.y - proj_br[0].y;
        total += (x * x + y * y);

        return total;
    }
    return 0;
}

void MyPowell::powell(vector<double> &x, vector<vector<double>> &direc, double ftol, double &fval)
{
    vector<double> x1;
    vector<double> x2;
    vector<double> direc1;
    int myitmax = 20;
    if(N>500)
        myitmax = 10;
    else if (N > 300)
    {
        myitmax = 15;
    }
    double fx2, t, fx, dum, delta;
    fval = obj(x);
    int bigind;
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        x1.push_back(x[j]);
    }
    int iter = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        do
        {
            do
            {
                iter += 1;
                fx = fval;
                bigind = 0;
                delta = 0.0;
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                {
                    direc1 = direc[i];
                    fx2 = fval;
                    linmin(x, direc1, N, fval);
                    if (fabs(fx2 - fval) > delta)
                    {
                        delta = fabs(fx2 - fval);
                        bigind = i;
                    }
                }
                if (2.0 * fabs(fx - fval) <= ftol * (fabs(fx) + fabs(fval)) + 1e-7)
                {
                    erase(direc1, x2, x1);
                    return;
                }
                if (iter >= itmax)
                {
                    cout << "powell exceeding maximum iterations" << endl;
                    return;
                }
                if (!x2.empty())
                {
                    x2.clear();
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                {
                    x2.push_back(2.0*x[j] - x1[j]);
                    direc1[j] = x[j] - x1[j];
                    x1[j] = x[j];
                }
                myitmax--;
                cout << fx2 << endl;
                fx2 = obj(x2);
                if (myitmax < 0)
                    return;
            } while (fx2 >= fx);

            dum = fx - 2 * fval + fx2;
            t = 2.0*dum*pow((fx - fval - delta), 2) - delta * pow((fx - fx2), 2);

        } while (t >= 0.0);
        linmin(x, direc1, N, fval);
        direc[bigind] = direc1;
    } 
}

double MyPowell::sign(double a)//, double b)
{
    if (a > 0.0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (a < 0.0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

double MyPowell::sqr(double a)
{
    return a * a;
}

void MyPowell::linmin(vector<double>& p, vector<double>& xit, int n, double &fret)
{
    double tol = 1e-2;
    ncom = n;
    pcom = p;
    xicom = xit;
    double ax = 0.0;
    double xx = 1.0;
    double bx = 0.0;
    double fa, fb, fx, xmin;
    mnbrak(ax, xx, bx, fa, fx, fb);
    fret = brent(ax, xx, bx, xmin, tol);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        xit[i] = (xmin * xit[i]);
        p[i] += xit[i];
    }
}

void MyPowell::mnbrak(double & ax, double & bx, double & cx, 
    double & fa, double & fb, double & fc)
{
    const double GOLD = 1.618034, GLIMIT = 110.0, TINY = 1e-20;
    double val, fw, tmp2, tmp1, w, wlim;
    double denom;
    fa = f1dim(ax);
    fb = f1dim(bx);
    if (fb > fa)
    {
        val = ax;
        ax = bx;
        bx = val;
        val = fb;
        fb = fa;
        fa = val;
    }
    cx = bx + GOLD * (bx - ax);
    fc = f1dim(cx);
    int iter = 0;
    while (fb >= fc)
    {
        tmp1 = (bx - ax) * (fb - fc);
        tmp2 = (bx - cx) * (fb - fa);
        val = tmp2 - tmp1;
        if (fabs(val) < TINY)
        {
            denom = 2.0*TINY;
        }
        else
        {
            denom = 2.0*val;
        }
        w = bx - ((bx - cx)*tmp2 - (bx - ax)*tmp1) / (denom);
        wlim = bx + GLIMIT * (cx - bx);
        if ((bx - w) * (w - cx) > 0.0)
        {
            fw = f1dim(w);
            if (fw < fc)
            {
                ax = bx;
                fa = fb;
                bx = w;
                fb = fw;
                return;
            }
            else if (fw > fb)
            {
                cx = w;
                fc = fw;
                return;
            }
            w = cx + GOLD * (cx - bx);
            fw = f1dim(w);
        }
        else 
        {
            if ((cx - w)*(w - wlim) >= 0.0)
            {
                fw = f1dim(w);
                if (fw < fc)
                {
                    bx = cx;
                    cx = w;
                    w = cx + GOLD * (cx - bx);
                    fb = fc;
                    fc = fw;
                    fw = f1dim(w);
                }
            }
            else if ((w - wlim)*(wlim - cx) >= 0.0)
            {
                w = wlim;
                fw = f1dim(w);
            }
            else
            {
                w = cx + GOLD * (cx - bx);
                fw = f1dim(w);
            }
        }

        ax = bx;
        bx = cx;
        cx = w;
        fa = fb;
        fb = fc;
        fc = fw;
    }
}

double MyPowell::f1dim(double x)
{
    vector<double> xt;
    for (int j = 0; j < ncom; j++)
    {
        xt.push_back(pcom[j] + x * xicom[j]);
    }
    return obj(xt);
}

double MyPowell::brent(double ax, double bx, double cx, double & xmin, double tol = 1.48e-8)
{
    const double CGOLD = 0.3819660, ZEPS = 1.0e-4;
    int itmax = 500;
    double a = MIN(ax, cx);
    double b = MAX(ax, cx);
    double v = bx;
    double w = v, x = v;
    double deltax = 0.0;
    double fx = f1dim(x);
    double fv = fx;
    double fw = fx;
    double rat = 0, u = 0, fu;
    int iter;
    int done;
    double dx_temp, xmid, tol1, tol2, tmp1, tmp2, p;
    for (iter = 0; iter < 500; iter++)
    {
        xmid = 0.5 * (a + b);
        tol1 = tol * fabs(x) + ZEPS;
        tol2 = 2.0*tol1;
        if (fabs(x - xmid) <= (tol2 - 0.5*(b - a)))
            break;
        done = -1;
        if (fabs(deltax) > tol1)
        {
            tmp1 = (x - w) * (fx - fv);
            tmp2 = (x - v) * (fx - fw);
            p = (x - v) * tmp2 - (x - w) * tmp1;
            tmp2 = 2.0 * (tmp2 - tmp1);
            if (tmp2 > 0.0)
                p = -p;
            tmp2 = fabs(tmp2);
            dx_temp = deltax;
            deltax = rat;
            if ((p > tmp2 * (a - x)) && (p < tmp2 * (b - x)) &&
                fabs(p) < fabs(0.5 * tmp2 * dx_temp))
            {
                rat = p / tmp2;
                u = x + rat;
                if ((u - a) < tol2 || (b - u) < tol2)
                {
                    rat = fabs(tol1) * sign(xmid - x);
                }
                done = 0;
            }

        }
        if(done)
        {
            if (x >= xmid)
            {
                deltax = a - x;
            }
            else
            {
                deltax = b - x;
            }
            rat = CGOLD * deltax;
        }
        if (fabs(rat) >= tol1)
        {
            u = x + rat;
        }
        else
        {
            u = x + fabs(tol1) * sign(rat);
        }
        fu = f1dim(u);

        if (fu > fx)
        {
            if (u < x)
            {
                a = u;
            }
            else
            {
                b = u;
            }
            if (fu <= fw || w == x)
            {
                v = w;
                w = u;
                fv = fw;
                fw = fu;
            }
            else if (fu <= fv || v == x || v == w)
            {
                v = u;
                fv = fu;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (u >= x)
                a = x;
            else
                b = x;
            v = w;
            w = x;
            x = u;
            fv = fw;
            fw = fx;
            fx = fu;
        }
    }
    if(iter > itmax)
        cout << "\n Brent exceed maximum iterations.\n\n";
    xmin = x;
    return fx;
}

vector<double> MyPowell::usePowell()
{
    ftol = 1e-4;
    vector<vector<double>> xi;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        vector<double> xii;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            xii.push_back(0);
        }
        xii[i]=(1.0);
        xi.push_back(xii);
    }
    double fret = 0;
    powell(myparams, xi, ftol, fret);
    //for (int i = 0; i < xi.size(); i++)
    //{
    //  double a = obj(xi[i]);
    //  if (fret > a)
    //  {
    //      fret = a;
    //      myparams = xi[i];
    //  }
    //}
    cout << "final result" << fret << endl;
    return myparams;
}

void MyPowell::erase(vector<double>& pbar, vector<double>& prr, vector<double>& pr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pbar.size(); i++)
    {
        pbar[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < prr.size(); i++)
    {
        prr[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < pr.size(); i++)
    {
        pr[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer? If you want to get hints on how to improve your code it would be better to post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It actually find smallest distance between to vectors, but it is not the best solution

Answer (score 0):

I used [PRAXIS](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/praxis/praxis.html) library, because it doesn't need derivative information and is fast.
I modified the code a little to my needs and now it is faster than original version written in Python.